# C++ template with constant and variable variations

Tags: c++, templates

I would like to make a template that supports variations for using either compile time constants or dynamic variables that can be changed at runtime to support optimal variations for each code path.

A simple example would be something like this, a little class that increments a number up to a defined saturation point:

```
template< typename T, T aSatValue >
class cIncrementor
{
public:
    typedef cIncrementor< T, aSatValue >    tIncrementor;

    cIncrementor( T aValue ) { mValue = aValue; }

    tIncrementor & operator++ ( int )
    {
        if( mValue >= aSatValue )
        {
            mValue = aSatValue;
        }
        else
        {
            mValue++;
        }
        return( *this );
    }

    T mValue;
};
```

(The functionality of this class is not really important, the key thing I am trying to work out is a good pattern for support constant and variable data).

In this version, the saturation value is a constant that is defined at runtime, and you can use this template as so:

```
    cIncrementor<int,32> lIncer(0); // maximum value of 32 and start at 0
    lIncer++; // test incrementing
```

I want to have an optional variation of the class that can supply the saturation value dynamically at runtime, but I don't want to store the extra value in the class for the constant case, and I don't want to duplicate code.

What would be the best way to structure templates like this so they can work with either a constant value or a variable?

Thanks!

Comment: How limited is the runtime value range ?

Comment: _'work with either a constant value or a variable?'_ The problem is that templates are instantiated at compile time and you can't pass a variable as a template parameter. What you could do is to provide a setter for `mValue` though, and change it from that default value passed as template parameter at runtime using that setter method.

Comment: Why don't you want to store the extra value in the class?

Comment: I didn't want the value in the class in the const case as it is not needed. This specific class isn't really that important, it was more a design principle that would allow me to share algorithms that use either constant or variable data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "best practice" way of doing it that I know of.  However, templates can be used to accomplish almost anything.
This solution is a little complex, but since you asked...

```
template< typename T, T SatValue >
class ConstSatValue
{
public:
    ConstSatValue(T) { }  //ignore the parameter as its irrelevant

    constexpr T getSatValue()
    { return SatValue; }
};

template< typename T >
class DynamicSatValue
{
public:
    DynamicSatValue(T sat)
    : satValue(sat) { }

    T getSatValue()
    { return satValue; }

private:
    T satValue;
};

template< typename T, typename aSatValue >
class cIncrementor: private aSatValue
{
public:
    typedef cIncrementor< T, aSatValue >    tIncrementor;

    cIncrementor( T aValue, T satValue = 0 )
    : aSatValue(satValue), mValue(aValue) { }

    tIncrementor & operator++ ( int )
    {
        T satValue = getSatValue(); //assumed present in base class
        if( mValue >= satValue )
        {
            mValue = satValue;
        }
        else
        {
            mValue++;
        }
        return( *this );
    }

    T mValue;
};
```

You use it like this:

```
cIncrementor<int, ConstSatValue<int, 32>> constBounded(0);
int bound = 32;
cIncrementor<int, DynamicSatValue<int>> dynamicBounded(0, bound);
```

This depends on the empty base class optimization and constexpr to get the behavior you want.  It gives the compiler all the information it needs to not store a saturation point in the compile-time constant case, while still providing an interface for a dynamic bound.

However, I would still strongly consider whether this extra complexity is worth the very small amount of memory you save as a result.

Comment: You may want to consider encapsulation rather than derivation in the solution. i.e. make aSatValue a member rather than a base class.
This removes the un-necessary is-a relationship between `cIncrementor` and `aSatValue`.

Comment: @RichardHodges I specifically used it as a base class so that the empty base class optimization could be used (class members can't have 0 size, but base classes can). Since the OP wanted to save memory this seemed the best choice. Also, since the inheritance is private the is-a relationship isn't really an issue.

Answer (score 2):

### The answer

There's no way to satisfy all of your requirements:

- no code duplication
- no extra objects in the class
- dynamic saturation value

It's simply not possible because to supply a runtime object you need an object in which to store this runtime value.

### What I'd do

If your saturation value needs to be constant and can be provided at runtime, the best shot you have is to have an extra `const` object inside the class:

```
template< typename T >
struct cIncrementor
{

    cIncrementor( const T& aValue, const T& bValue) 
        : mValue(aValue)
        , sValue(bValue)
        {}

    cIncrementor & operator++ ( int )
    {
        if( mValue >= sValue )
        {
            mValue = sValue;
        }
        else
        {
            mValue++;
        }
        return( *this );
    }

    T mValue;
    const T sValue;

};
```

Also remember that the ways of compiler optimizations are infinite.